# Wordpress Contributors?

Tags: wordpress

I'm currently using Wordpress.com to host my blog, but I would like more control over it so I am about to setup my own self hosted wordpress. Currently the one on Wordpress.com I have 4 contributors that are signed up and would like to know if there is a way to transfer these accounts over to my self-hosted wordpress without having to create an account for each contributor again.

Is this possible.

Sorry if it is a little confusing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The contributors are records in your database; you will transfer this database as part of creating your new blog, so you'll get these 4 accounts for free in the transfer process.